# Why is this powershell script taking so long? It is crashing my GUI

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, powershell

```
$connectionString = "Data Source=iaosd;Initial Catalog=fasdasd;User ID=sdfsdfsfd;Password=sd0fuisdofij;Connect Timeout=60"

$timer = [Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew()

# test db connectivity
try {
    $sqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection -ErrorAction Stop
    $sqlConnection.ConnectionString = $connectionString
    $sqlConnection.Open()
    $sqlConnection.Close()
    Write-Host "connection successful"
} catch {
    Write-Host "ERROR"
}

$timer.stop() 

Write-Host $timer.Elapsed
```

Hi, This code actually works immediately if $dbServer is localhost and the other details are correct. But when I change the $dbserver to some random text it takes around 1 minute to complete and it crashes my gui. If I don't put any text in $dbServer the try catch works as expected

"Exception calling "Open" with "0" argument(s): "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible

- CategoryInfo : NotSpecified (:) [], MethodInvocationException
- Fully QualifiedErrorId : SqlException "

Comment: Sorry, I tried your code, and it worked fine.  If I changed the $dbserver to something invalid, the call to $sqlConnection.Open() throws the exception, it is caught by the catch, and 'ERROR' is printed.

Comment: Write-Host "[$connectionString]" to check if it is OK. Check from another computer.

Comment: @toastifer Oh. What version of Powershell are you using? I'm currently using 5.1.19041.1682 and Powershell is hanging on $sqlConnection.Open()

Comment: Works (well, the ```catch``` block is executed) here as well on Windows PowerShell 5.1.22000.832 if I just cut & paste your sample code verbatim. Have you got an example of a literal connection string (i.e. just plain text, no variables) that fails for you?

Comment: Data Source=iaosd;Initial Catalog=fasdasd;User ID=sdfsdfsfd;Password=sd0fuisdofij;Connect Timeout=60. 
Also I'm doing some further tests right now. This section of code does crash my GUI but when I isolate this code (in a separate script) it does eventually hit the catch however it takes about 1 minute to do this (I timed it with Diagnostics.Stopwatch]. I have tested this 4 times and each time it took exactly 1 minute to complete +- 30ms.

Comment: @mclayton I just tried it on another computer with a fresh install of powershell 9.16 and again the script took 1 minute 2 seconds to tun. Do you know why it is taking so long? I have updated my original post with the code I'm running.

Comment: Sounds like it's polling for servers on your network, and waiting for it to time out. Your connection string has `Timeout=60` in it, which would be 1 minute, which would explain the delay. Since you're running your code in the main GUI thread, that would lock your GUI for a full minute as well. Are you on a domain?

Comment: Connect to database with SQL Server Management Studio and in explorer look at log files under Management.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling the [`.Open()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.open?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0#system-data-sqlclient-sqlconnection-open) method from [`SqlConnection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) will block your thread which explains why your GUI app is crashing.

The alternatives you could use are either, opening the connection inside a [Runspace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.runspaces.runspace?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0) which runs in a different thread hence the GUI wouldn't freeze. If you decide to go this route, these answers can help you out with the code:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/72724752/15339544
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/73998096/15339544
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/73549224/15339544

Otherwise, the other alternative you have could be using the [`OpenAsync()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dbconnection.openasync?view=net-6.0&viewFallbackFrom=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0#system-data-common-dbconnection-openasync) method from the class, and wait for the [`Task`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task?view=net-7.0) to complete using a loop, this **would block the thread** but only for milliseconds, 200 to be precise in this example. It's also worth noting you could reduce the [`TimeOut`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectiontimeout?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0#system-data-sqlclient-sqlconnection-connectiontimeout) by changing `Connect Timeout=60` in your connection string.

```bash
try {
    $connectionString = "Data Source=iaosd;Initial Catalog=fasdasd;User ID=sdfsdfsfd;Password=sd0fuisdofij;Connect Timeout=10"
    $sqlConnection    = [Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection] $connectionString

    $task = $sqlConnection.OpenAsync()

    do {
        $response = $task.Wait(200)
        # Assuming this would be an event of a WinForms App,
        # here you could use:
        # [System.Windows.Forms.Application]::DoEvents()
        # To gain control over your form while waiting.
        # Not the best of practices though useful for simple events.
    } until($response)

    $task.GetAwaiter().GetResult()
}
catch {
    $w32except = $_.Exception.InnerException.InnerException.InnerException
    if($w32except -is [ComponentModel.Win32Exception]) {
        return Write-Error $w32except
    }
    Write-Error $_
}
finally {
    $sqlConnection, $task | ForEach-Object Dispose
}
```

I've added inline comments assuming this could be an event of a [WinForms App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms?view=windowsdesktop-7.0), though I definitely recommend you to read [**Remarks**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.doevents?view=windowsdesktop-6.0#remarks) from [`Application.DoEvents` Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.doevents?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) in detail.